# Input for currency not treating 0 like other numbers after decimal

Tags: html, reactjs, input

I'm make a react application that takes an input that should be shown to two decimal places. When the default input has a one number after the decimal, it should add a second number with a 0 after it. It also lets me add infinite amounts of "0"s, but caps any other number at 2 decimal places.

Two different problems pictured:

Case 1.
This is how the input looks when first loaded. The preferred display would be 1.60 (two decimal places)

[image]

Case 2.
Current behavior allows the user to add infinite 0s (any other number it caps at 2 decimal places). Expected behavior should cap all numbers including 0s at 2 decimal places.

[image]

```js
function ProductMaterial() {
        const [name, setName] = useState("");

        function handleChange(e) {
            let val = e.target.value;
            if (val.includes(".") && val.split(".")[1].length > 2) {
            } 
            else {
                setName(parseFloat(val));
                setMaterialState(parseFloat(val));
            }

        }

        return (
            <div className="input-group-sm col-xs-2 material input-group">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                    <span className="input-group-text">$</span>
                </div>
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type="number"
                    min="0.00"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={product.material}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Here is the code for setMaterialState. It changes the product.material value, and then calls `setMaterial()` in a `useEffect()` function. The `setMaterial()` takes the id of the product, and the new material value and saves it to state.

```js
    function setMaterialState(newMaterial) {
        product.material = newMaterial;
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setMaterial(product.id, product.material);
    }, [product.material]);
```

I know that the issue here is that on first load nothing is triggering the `onChange()` function. I've tried setting `value={product.material}` to `value={product.material.toFixed(2)}` but it makes it difficult to fix the input. Is there a good way to initialize it before, maybe using a `UseEffect()` statement? And on top of this I'm not sure why the 0s can be added indefinitely.

---

Update:
The first problem with the leading 0s was solved by using the `onKeyPress=` answer suggested by Photonic.

However, I'm still struggling on the forcing it to be two decimal places when there is a 0 at the end problem. I'm realizing that the issue with not starting doing 1.60 is due to it being converted to a float value and not being a string. I tried doing a UseEffect() [] and force it to go to 2 decimal places with product.material.toFixed(); as well as modify the data to start with being 1.60, but it seems like the only way to force the two decimal places is keeping it as a string or converting it to a string by using `product.material.toFixed(2)`. The value in the input `value={product.material}` need to be a number to correctly execute calculations and collect user input. I'm not sure what the best solution for this is.

Comment: Can you include the code that covers where `material` and `materialState` are defined?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's code omitted from `handleChange` but, with what's currently shown, the state updates only happen if the input value has a decimal point and more than two digits after it, so none of that logic is happening when you add more digits after the point (but that would apply to any digit, not just zero)

Comment: @HenryWoody I added additional code! 
I'm sorry if my code is hard to read! The code should be ignoring any values entered after there are two decimal points and only executes anything if there are less than two decimal places within the else() statement. I put the else statement on a new line so it is easier to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you are initializing the first load but you can use `UseEffect()` to fix the decimal place issue like you mentioned.

For the infinite decimal places...

`onChange` is an event that is already happen, you might want to try changing from `onChange` to `onKeyDown` or `onKeyPress` and in your code you can add `e.preventDefault()` to stop number from being entered

```
if (val.includes(".") && val.split(".")[1].length > 2) {
   e.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
`e.preventdefault()` doesn't seem to change anything for some reason... I tried using `onKeyDown` and `onKeyPress` instead of `onChange`. They both cap the additional 0 input at the third decimal place (ex. I can add two 0s to 1.6, making it 1.600). However I cannot delete anything or add any number other than 0, even when I'm at 1.6. I don't understand why 0s are acting so differently. My other code works perfect for any number that isn't 0.

Comment: Update: I added the onChange back in addition to the onKeyPress and now it works with normal numbers still as well as handles the 0s being capped to 3 decimal places as described in the previous comment (1.6 can become 1.600). I made a second function named handlePress with the same code, except the if statement checking for 1 number after the decimal place rather than 2 and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function when the 'component did mount' you can use

```
useEffect(yourFunction(){}, [])
```